# Is there an alternative to JPasswordField?

Tags: java, swing, passwords

When typing a passphrase like

```
yeast bulk seize is shows pain
```

everybody can hear tapping the space bar, so it seems logical to display the spaces in the password field, too. So I'd like something capable of showing

```
***** **** ***** ** ***** ****
```

instead of

```
******************************
```

This would make typing easier while hardly decreasing the security.

---

#### UPDATE

Think twice before you update  Riduidel's comment. When [Bruce Schneier writes](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/06/the_problem_wit_2.html) *"It's time to show most passwords in clear text"*, then showing a small part of it must be correct, too. Especially showing a part which may get captured simply by listening.

Comment: **hardly** ? My foot ! Due to usages, the presence of the ` ` (whitespace) character significantly increases the password quality. Revealing this character, which considerably increases search space - and as a consequence time to crack password -, would in fact significantly decreases security.

Comment: 1. Space is just another character. 2. [Who says password masking is actually more secure](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/passwords.html)? 3. The people who can hear you hammering on your space bar **are not the people who want to steal your password.**

Comment: From my point of view this is absolutely not worth the effort. Actually I don't see any added value in it at all. But its your chice of course.

Comment: @Matt: I've read that article before and I'd say it's a pretty narrow viewpoint.  If you disagree, consider entering your password while connected to a projector with 50 people in the room.  It doesn't matter if they wanted to steal your password, now they know it without even looking for it, and I'm sorry but I don't trust everyone completely.  I would absolutely hate a product that didn't give me at least an option of masking it.  I personally like how most WLAN password inputs work, allowing you to toggle off the mask.

Comment: @Mark: I agree that Nielsen's viewpoint is a narrow one (it's **all** about usability), and I also agree that a pretty good solution is to allow the mask to be toggled. Nielsen actually mentions that: _"It's therefore worth offering them a checkbox to have their passwords masked."_ My main point was that, by far, the biggest security risk is **not** Mike in next cubicle over, who keeps sticking his head over the divider.

Comment: As for password masking see what [Bruce Schneier says](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/06/the_problem_wit_2.html). @Riduidel If somebody can hear the space, why they should not see it too??? If somebody sees the spaces in a passphrase like this they could simply give up (except they work for the NSA :D).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a variation that uses [`setEchoChar()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar%28char%29) to make the password visible for a predefined time: three seconds for example.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339702 */
public class PasswordTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Test Password");
        JPasswordField jpwd = new JPasswordField();
        TimedPasswordListener tpl = new TimedPasswordListener(jpwd);
        jpwd.getDocument().addDocumentListener(tpl);
        jf.add(jpwd);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class TimedPasswordListener implements DocumentListener, ActionListener {

    private Timer timer = new Timer(3000, this);
    private char echoChar;
    private JPasswordField pwf;

    public TimedPasswordListener(JPasswordField jp) {
        pwf = jp;
        timer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        showText(e);
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        showText(e);
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    public void showText(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (0 != pwf.getEchoChar()) {
            echoChar = pwf.getEchoChar();
        }
        pwf.setEchoChar((char) 0);
        timer.restart();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        pwf.setEchoChar(echoChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: NB: This approach does not address other legitimate security questions raised in this question. In particular, it may leave clear text in memory for an indeterminate period.

Comment: @maaartinus: Good point. The approach can't _improve_ security beyond its scope; but to my knowledge, it doesn't make it _worse_. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983964).

Answer (score 4):

Was thinking [`JPasswordField`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html) was simply a  [`JTextField`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) simply overriding the renderer component, but it seems not to be the case.

So, instead of changing the renderer (like it would be the case if `JTextField` had such a component), you'll have to use a `JTextField` with a custom [`Document`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) holding two strings :

1. Password text as written by user
2. Displayed password

You'll have to make sure all `Document` modifying methods change the password text, while all rendering methods use the displayed one.

Comment: There are many things different, especially JPasswordField not creating any String for the password and using a char[] instead. This is quite important for the security as you can clear a char[] but not a String.