# Change copy behavior of a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable, copy-paste

By default, when you try to copy from a `JTable`, the `toString` method of the value(s) being copied are sent to the clipboard. How can I change this behavior for one class of objects?

Let's say I have a table with two columns for simplicity's sake. The first column has `Boolean`s in it and the second column has `String`s. Currently when you copy a `Boolean`, you get either `true` or `false`. How could I change this behavior to place an arbitrary string on the clipboard (say `t` for `true` and `f` for `false`) without changing the copy behavior of `String`?

Here's a SSCCE where you can copy / paste from a `JTable`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class ChangeCopyBehavior {
    private static class TestModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -774558262249729206L;

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return col == 0 ? Boolean.class : String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 1) {
                return "String";
            } else {
                return rowIndex % 2 == 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTable table = new JTable(new TestModel());
                table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                panel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                panel.add(new JTextArea("Paste stuff here"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting Password row and Pasting in notepad reveals the password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776754/selecting-password-row-and-pasting-in-notepad-reveals-the-password)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom TransferHandler to export the data in whatever format you want.

Here is a link to the old [ExtendedDnDDemo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ExtendedDnDDragandDropDemo.htm) from the Swing tutorial that show an example of a custom TableTransferHandler.

Answer (score 2):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776754/selecting-password-row-and-pasting-in-notepad-reveals-the-password/8776974) where I gave an example of [custom copy-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776754/selecting-password-row-and-pasting-in-notepad-reveals-the-password/8776974#comment11007808_8776974) using a SwingX `JXTable`. However, that same approach can be used with a regular `JTable`