# KeyStroke with keys 1-9 does not work with JTextComponent's Keymap

Tags: java, swing, keymapping, jtextcomponent

For some unknown reason, this code doesn't work.

```
JTextComponent component = new JTextArea();
Keymap keymap = component.getKeymap();
keymap.addActionForKeyStroke(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), myAction);
```

It never triggers `myAction` when I press Alt and 1 (not on the numpad, the 1 above the letters). This also does not work for any modifier.

The solution given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11974908/3838784 does not work, the action is still not triggered. Removing all keystrokes from the key map that have ALT as a modifier does not seem to help either.

Comment: Looks as if the problem only happens with 1-9 keys (not the numpad ones)

Comment: 1-9 keys? action triggered when i press alt+q

Comment: @Fast Snail I know, but if you replace VK_Q by VK_1 it does not work. EDIT : I edited the question.

Comment: `vk_1` also works.show complete minimal example

Comment: That's extremely weird. I replaced my code by the one  i provided and it still doesn't work. May be a bug.

Comment: cannot say anything without seeing your complete code

Answer (score 1):

I tried a sample, using your code, it seems to be working fine. Can you let me know if anything is different from your code?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.Keymap;

public class MyExample extends JFrame {

    MyExample() {
        initGUI();
    } // Constructor

    private void initGUI() {
        // Create the button
        JButton myButton = new JButton("Press ME !");

        // Create the label
        JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("TEST !!!");

        // Set up the window 
        JPanel pane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        pane.add(myButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(testLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JTextComponent component = new JTextArea();
        pane.add(component, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Keymap keymap = component.getKeymap();

        keymap.addActionForKeyStroke(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), new MyAction());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        // setSize(600,300);  

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Set System L&F
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // handle exception
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        // new MyExample().setVisible(true);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            MyExample me = new MyExample();
            me.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    class MyAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Action performed");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your sample is not working for me. This must be a bug on Ubuntu MATE or something, both OpenJDK and Oracle JDK do not work when running this test... :(

Comment: yep i might be. I m not using ubuntu, so it would bot possible for me to check. But this works in Windows.