# How to get value of a JTable cell during edit

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

The solution I have seen so far is listen cell change i.e.

```
    TableModelListener tableModelListener = new TableModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {

                row = e.getFirstRow();
                col = e.getColumn();

                // do something
            }
        }
    };
```

But I need to get the cell value, selectedRow & selectedColumn when typing, and before hitting enter. How to do it?

Comment: _I need to get the cell value, selectedRow & selectedColumn when typing, and before hitting enter_ - sounds weird: it doesn't change while editing, so you can grab it before starting the edit ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8302423/230513), or a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611820/230513), in your [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).

Comment: Thank you for your information but I am still new to Java and need more time to understand these.

Comment: You definitely need a `CellEditor`, which will tell you `row` & `column`; don't hesitate to update your question going forward.

Comment: @trashgod, please provide example on where to place the `DocumentListener` on the extended `DefaultCellEditor` based on the link you provided. What method do I need to override? I have the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Add the listener to the text component used by the `CellEditor`, which is `JTextField` in the example cited. Ping me if you pose a new question.

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

```
 if (jTable1.getCellEditor() == null) {
                    System.out.println("Not Edited");

                } else {

            System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),jTable1.getSelectedColumn()));
    }
```

where jTable1 is your JTable Name

Comment: the question is a bit strange, but whatever it really wants - this isn't an anser ;-)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer, not exactly suited for your particular needs (as they are hard to achieve anyway) but it helped me

Answer (score 0):

Use [TableCellListener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) for listening to the changes in the `TableModel`. By using this you can get the `row-index`, `column-index`, `old-value` and `new-value` of the edited cell in the table.

Comment: My needs is exactly same as Mubashir:
This requires pressing enter key, what i require is that when the value is changed the event automatically fires. I am checking the DocumentEvent now.

Comment: Mubashir is the thread replyier in your TableCellListener link who replied on March 19, 2012

Comment: This is exactly what OP doesn't want. This only fires the event when the editing has stopped.