# Get cell values of jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a jtable with column item,quantity,rate and amount.If i enter value in quantity and press tab key the total amount is getting calculated that is working fine.But i need the amount to be calculated on typing the quantity.
I want it to be done on key pressed of numbers or on typing number.I have used default jtable using netbeans

Comment: So, you it so that as the user types, the `amount` is calculated in real time?

Comment: yes,on billing when particular items quantity is entered the amount must be calculated.

Comment: But why the header says get cell values of jtable?

Comment: Forgive me, but why is it important that this is done in real time?

Comment: You need to understand how the `TableCellEditor` works. You need to add an `ActionListener` to the `TableCellEditor` component and then you can do whatever you want.

Comment: The issue is, the editor shouldn't be changing the state of the table, this leads you down a slippery slope of problems, hacks and work arounds...

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14540685/44522 (it's quite a duplicate question)

Answer (score 3):

to get cell value you can to do something like that

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex)
```

Comment: Yes, because there are two layers top is table(model) low is text editor(cell), the value is present on lovest layer and you can reach it using TableCellEditor (as described above), after "flushing" data, value will be present in table model (top layer) and can be reached by my exaple.

Answer (score 3):

In response to an answer suggesting `getValueAt()`, you say, "I used the above code but it prints as `null`." As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513), the value is not available in the model until the editor concludes. You'll need a custom [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) that uses a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to update your total.