# Displaying the password in a JPasswordField rather than setting 0 as an echo char

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

How do I display the text of a JPasswordField rather than set 0 as an echo char?

Java Docs says:

> Setting a value of 0 indicates that you wish to see the text as it is typed, similar to the behavior of a standard JTextField.

The following results in an Incompatible types error

```
outField.setEchoChar(0);
```

wheras

```
outField.setEchoChar('0');
```

simply sets 0 as the echo char (displays 0s for every digit).

The reason for using JPasswordField over JTextField is that I want to change the echo char and hide the password with another method.

Thanks!

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5342146/230513).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
outField.setEchoChar((char)0);
```

If you do this:

```
outField.setEchoChar(0);
```

then 0 is an integer, not a char, and the method requires a char.

If you do this:

```
outField.setEchoChar('0');
```

then '0' is equivalent to (char)48.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
outField.setEchoChar(0);
```

you're trying to pass an int into the method, and this isn't allowed since it expects a char type. Instead try

```
outField.setEchoChar((char)0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the char with value 0, not the number 0, or the char '0':

```
    outField.setEchoChar((char)0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it out like this......

```
outField.setEchoChar((char)0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try `outField.setEchoChar('\0');`