# JPasswordField KeyPress string length error?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, string-length, jpasswordfield

I am trying to change background colors of a JPasswordField in Java Swing (Netbeans).

Here's what I have:

```
private void pstxtPasswordKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         

    //Get string from password box
    userPassword = new String(pstxtPassword.getPassword());

    //If password is 8+ characters
    //(one less because string counting begins at 0)
    if (userPassword.length() >= 7) {

        //Set password input box background color to green
        pstxtPassword.setBackground(Color.green);
    }

    else { //If password is less than 8 characters

        //Set password input box background color to red
        pstxtPassword.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

}
```

Everything works, except when I backspace. When I backspace after typing 8+ characters, the color doesn't change back to red until there is only 5 characters left in the field.

Help would be appreciated, I am very new to java programming and Netbeans.

EDIT:
I have changed my code,

```
    //If password is 8+ characters
    if ((pstxtPassword.getPassword()).length >= 8) {

        //Set password input box background color to green
        pstxtPassword.setBackground(Color.green);
    }

    else { //If password is less than 8 characters

        //Set password input box background color to red
        pstxtPassword.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
```

This code seems to make sense to me, but in testing, the color changes green at the 9th character; when backspacing, it changes back to red at 6. This seems to be the same problem I had when the code was `>= 7` where the color changed green at the 8th character, but changed back to red at 5 characters.

[image: After typing 9 characters, the component turns green]

After typing 9 characters, the component turns green

[image: After backspacing (starting from 9), component remains green until there are 6 characters]

After backspacing (starting from 9), component remains green until there are 6 characters

This is strange, because I have similar code in a button in this program which displays an error message. That code works fine.
Is this a KeyPress problem, perhaps something to do with the backspace key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an aside, examine the length of the array returned by `getPassword()`, rather than the length of a `String` constructed from that array. The `String` is a security risk, as it will be stored for an indefinite time with the easily found name `userPassword`.

Addendum: Here's a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5342146/230513) of Robin's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12968493/230513) to use `DocumentListener`. I'm guessing that your key listener is seeing the `KeyEvent` before the `JPasswordField` has processed it.

Comment: @Jaybob: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5342146/230513) of Robin's suggestion to use `DocumentListener`. I'm guessing that your key listener is seeing the `KeyEvent` before the `JPasswordField` has processed it.

Answer (score 8):

Since `JPasswordField` extends from `JTextComponent`, you can attach a `DocumentListener` to it which is a far safer manner to update the background color on each change of the contents.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (userPassword.length() >= 7)
```

This if statement doesn't match your comments:

//If password is 8+ characters

The actual code says if there are 7+ characters, then turn the background green. So when you are backspacing, it should turn the background red when you are down to 6 characters left.

I think your confusion is shown in this comment:

```
//(one less because string counting begins at 0)
```

What you are trying to describe is that *indexing* a character in a `String` starts at `0`, for example when you use `charAt()` or `subString()`. This means that the first character is at index `0`, the second at index `1`, etc. On the other hand, `length()` returns the number of characters in the `String`. This is has nothing to do with the indexing, so you don't need to subtract 1.

Comment: OK, so `length()` returns the number of characters in a string.
I originally had `if (userPassword.length() >= 8`. However, after testing, when I typed in 8 characters the background was still red, when I typed the 9th character, the background would change to green. I changed it to `>= 7` and it for some reason worked. I still cannot figure out why it stays green until I backspace to 5 characters. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Jaybob To debug this code, I would start by printing out the value of `userPassword` to make sure it is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using KeyRelease instead of KeyPress, try it out my friend

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
private void pstxtPasswordKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
```

Instead of

```
private void pstxtPasswordKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
```