# Compare two JPasswordFields in Java before saving?

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if JPassword field is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460582/how-to-check-if-jpassword-field-is-null)

While creating a login registration form, I am using two password fields. Before saving the data, I want to compare both fields; and if they match, then the data should be saved in file.  If not it should open a dialog box. Please can anyone help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show some effort before posting. I bet if you got the text from both password fields and compared them that would be a good start.

Answer (score 11):

The safest way would be to use [Arrays.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D%29):

```
if (Arrays.equals(passwordField1.getPassword(), passwordField2.getPassword())) {
   // save data
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

**Explanation:** `JPassword.getText` was purposely deprecated to avoid using `Strings` in favor of using a `char[]` returned by `getPassword`.

When calling `getText` you get a String (immutable object) that may not be changed (except reflection) and so the password stays in the memory until garbage collected.

A char array however may be modified, so the password will really not stay in memory.

This above solution is in keeping with that approach.

Comment: +1 ahh trying to optimize on me ??? :)

Answer (score 3):

It would help to show what you have tried...

but you'd do it something like:

```
//declare fields

JPasswordField jpf1=...;
JPasswordField jpf2=...;

...

 //get the password  from the passwordfields

String jpf1Text=Arrays.toString(jpf1.getPassword());//get the char array of password and convert to string represenation
String jpf2Text=Arrays.toString(jpf2.getPassword());

//compare the fields contents
if(jpf1Text.equals(jpf2Text)) {//they are equal

}else {//they are not equal

}
```

Comment: Note a potential [security risk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12966497/230513).