# Error on checking if value of textField is equal to string JAVA

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield, gettext

Hey im having trouble with checking if a JTextField value is given. I think I have the correct code, but it is not saying anything that could possible be broken.

Q: Why wont it display or run the Game.main(null) when the value of the textfield is "Dianamu" ?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   String values = textField1.getText();
   if(values == "Dianamu"){
       Game.main(null);
   }
   System.out.println("Login Works:");
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use .equals() to compare strings don't use ==

Comment: I would recommend to read what mr.Pshemo posted it explains why not to use ==.
you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

if(values.equals("Dianamu")){
    Game.main(null);
}

EXPLANATION:
== compares object references; .equals() compares values

Comment: Dumping code on an unexpecting OP isn't as helpful as it might seem (although I tend to do as well), take the time to explain why your approach should be used and why the OP's approach didn't work...

Comment: == compares object references; .equals() compares values

Comment: Don't tell me, tell the OP ;)

Comment: Good, now include it to your answer. To do that use [edit] option. Also format your code sample. You can do it with `{}` button from editor's menu.

Comment: How could this work with doing it with a JPasswordField? Would I need to de-code the password (Im just using local string variables for now to test)

Comment: about JPasswordField comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995986/compare-two-jpasswordfields-in-java-before-saving

Comment: @Heloic `field.getPassword()` will return array of characters. To create String that will represent content of JPasswordField you can use `new String(field.getPassword())` then you can use `equals` on this String and compare it with your other Strings like `new String(field.getPassword()).equals("secret")`.