# Echo jpassword character once and then hide it

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

In my swing application I want to echo jpassword field character for some time (1 second) and then again hide it. I want to do it character by character after user inputs a character (When user inputs a character, show it, then hide it. Then for all input characters repeat this).
Can someone tell me is it possible, if yes how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5342146/230513).

Comment: @trashgod That makes the **whole** password visible, right? Not just the recently typed character.

Comment: Yes; now you have a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which to experiment; feel free to cite it if you update your question.

Comment: @Andreas- I want exactly what you are saying.

Comment: @Andreas: Sorry, I meant to address the questioner. Thank you for helping to clarify the question.

Comment: @trashgod No issue :) Its good to have a starting point, even though it might be difficult to achieve the desired behavior through `JPasswordField` - probably through some `NavigationFilter` or similar as suggested by @mKorbel in a (now deleted) comment, but probably OP needs to subclass `JTextField` and implement his own `JPasswordField`

Comment: I would use a regular `JTextField` and keep the real string in the background document while manually setting an `*` as the displayed text.

Comment: If you can't manage it yourself, show what you tried and I'll post some code to direct you.

Comment: @user1803551- Are u going to use DocumentListener for the real string?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very complicated, you can disable the masking characters when you set this value to “0″ with this method: `setEchoChar((char) 0)`

```
pass.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        unhide();
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        unhide();
    }
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        unhide();
    }

    public void unhide(){
        pass.setEchoChar((char) 0);//display password
        //here your timer
        pass.setEchoChar('*');//hide with '*'
    }
});
```

The code above shows you a first idea of ​​what you should do. You'll have to use a thread to wait for the desired time.

Comment: As @Andreas suggested in a now deleted comment, "IMHO, OP wants to see the recent character only, like `p`, `*a`, `**s`, `***s`, etc.—similar to what some mobile apps do. From the `JPasswordField` javadoc, this seems not easy to achieve; it most likely requires a new component based on `JTextField`."

Answer (score 0):

I came across this which may be a good start as it displays the last char entered and shows the rest of the password is masked but doesn't hide it after a set time so you would probably need to implement an event to hide after set time [Check it out here](http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/password/MaskedPassword/demo.html)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something? It gives you a starting point for the masked text-box to do what you want minus the last char disappearing after a set point of time.

Comment: @user2991535 The question was about Java and the JPasswordField Swing component, not about Javascript and html