# What are the security reasons for JPasswordField.getPassword()?

Tags: java, security, swing, passwords, jpasswordfield

Since Java 1.2, `JPasswordField.getText()` has been deprecated "for security reasons", ecouraging usage of `getPassword()` method "for stronger securty".

However, I was able to get the password stored in `JPasswordField` at least in Oracle JRE 1.7 by analysing the heap dump (`JPasswordField instance -> model -> s -> array`).

So how does `JPasswordField.getPassword()` helps to protect the password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) for it states:

> For stronger security, it is recommended that the returned character array be cleared after use by setting each character to zero.

But, of course, if you use the `getText` method, you get back a String, which is immutable, so you couldn't carry out the same recommendation.

Comment: There still is a char array stored in `JPasswordField` itself, so why bother?

Comment: A character array can be cleared immediately. A `String` can be garbage collected at some indeterminate time in the future.

Comment: You mean, I need to clear the JPasswordField content immediately after using?

Comment: @FrozenSpider - that's the recommendation. I'm not able to check at the moment - is the array returned by `getPassword` the internal array you've been looking at, or a copy?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever returned array is a copy created via `System.arraycopy(...)`, so it seems that we need to clear both - one directly, and one via `setText(null)`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. Here is a pragmatic approach that explains the difference between `getPassword()` and `getText()`

```
JPasswordField jt=new JPasswordField("I am a password");
System.out.println("The text is "+jt.getText());
System.out.println("The password is "+jt.getPassword());
```

**Output**

```
I am a password
[C@1e4a47e
```

The `getPassword()` method returns the password as `char[]` whereas the `getText()` returns the password as plain text i.e. in the form of `String`.

However, if you do print like this,

```
System.out.println(new String(jt.getPassword()));
```

This is much equal to `getText()` in `JPasswordField`. However this does not mean that `getPassword()` uses the `getText()` internally and then convert it into `char` array.

The `getPassword()` method uses the non-string API i.e. the `Segment`. However, `Segment` is again immutable, but the `getPassword()` method brings the char array from the `Segment` and returns it.

However as `String` is immutable and `char[]` is not, a `char[]` is considered quite secure because it can be wiped out.

Answer (score 1):

Security note though getPassword() uses getText() internally

> Although the JPasswordField class inherits the getText method, you
>   should use the getPassword method instead. Not only is getText less
>   secure, but in the future it might return the visible string (for
>   example, "******") instead of the typed string.
>
> To further enhance security, once you are finished with the character
>   array returned by the getPassword method, you should set each of its
>   elements to zero.

Comment: Thanks for copy-pasting http://stackoverflow.com/a/984063/466646 , yes. And it's not an answer anyway, see my comment to @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer.

Comment: @FrozenSpider Changed the answer -