# how to empty the password field value(String) in java using swing

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

I have Textfield and password field.I am able to get the string written in the textfield and password field but not able to setting the text of password field empty.

The error comes "The method setText(String) is undefined for type string"

```
JTextField jtf=new JTextField(8);
JPasswordField jpwf=new JPasswordField(8);
String value= jtf.getText();
String jpwf= jpwfName.getText();
jtfName.setText("");
**Error on this line**//jpwf.setText("");
```

Comment: You have two declarations of the variable `jpwf`: `JPasswordField jpwf` and then `String jpwf`. That's not possible

Comment: You should not be using `JPassWordField#getText` (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/983964/1076463 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10443308/1076463)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the `setText()` method on the correct variable. Use

```
jpwf.setText("");
```

instead of

```
pwd.setText("");
```

There is also another problem before that, you declare twice the variable `jpwf` (once with `JPasswordField` and once with `String`). Maybe it's only a typo.

The error you get says that you have a variable `jpwf` of the type `String` on which there is no method named `setText()`.

Comment: sorry it got written wrong by mistake, I am calling jpwf.setText("");

Comment: @user1782870 update your post to reflect exactly what you have and where the error occurs.

Comment: JTextField jtf=new JTextField(8);
JPasswordField jpwf=new JPasswordField(8);
String value= jtf.getText();
String jpwf= jpwfName.getText();
jtfName.setText("");

Comment: and the callin function on the password field is jpwf.setText("");

Comment: @user1782870 Edit directly your post instead of posting comments. As I mentionned in my answer, you declare twice the variable `jpwf`. Read my answer again!

Answer (score 0):

u can user this code

```
    jpwf.setText("");
```

in the line of u typed like

```
  jtfName.setText("");
```