# Using getPassword() method and BCrypt

Tags: java, arrays, swing, char, bcrypt

I'm in the process of completing a login GUI and have been using `BCrypt` to encrypt a `String` password. After reading about deprecation warnings, where the [`getText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText%28%29) method is [not recommended for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443308/why-gettext-in-jpasswordfield-was-deprecated), I decided to to use [`getPassword()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) instead. However, as you are probably aware, it returns the password as a `char[]` array. How would I pass a `char[]` array into `BCrypt` without compromising security by converting the password into a `String`, which is accessible in memory?

Here is the `BCrypt` class: [`org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt`](http://code.google.com/p/jbcrypt/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/mindrot/jbcrypt/BCrypt.java)

Comment: What stops you from changing the signature of `hashpw()` and revising the code accordingly?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Password4j](https://github.com/Password4j/password4j) like this:

```
char[] password = passwordField.getPassword();
SecureString secure = new SecureString(password);

Password4j.hash(secure).withBCrypt();
// Clear the SecureString object
secure.clear();
```

You can find more info about `SecureString`s [here](https://github.com/Password4j/password4j#security-of-strings).