# JPasswordField security with action command

Tags: java, swing, security, jpasswordfield

I am using a `JPasswordField` in my program. When I ask `getPassword()`, I get a `char[]` array. But when I add an `ActionListener` to the `JPasswordField` and ask `getActionCommand()`, I get the password as a `String`. Is this password save in the event object as `String`? **Isn't this a security issue?**

Comment: Using a string is a security issue. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords (the answer from Jon Skeet) for details.

Comment: +1 good catch, sounds like a bug to me! Way out is to always set the actionCommand so it doesn't fallback to the default

Comment: +1 for a great find :-) Now are you going to report this to `Java Oracle` or not ?

Comment: It's widely known. http://stackoverflow.com/a/984151/4725 IIRC, you can also end up with remnants appearing undocumentedly in the `Document` and perhaps elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set no action command for a component, the text in it will be the action command.
This is why you are getting the password.

Even for `JTextField` also

```
JTextField jt=new JTextField("text");
        jt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                System.out.println(ae.getActionCommand());
            }
        });
```

This is a security issue because you are getting password as String which is immutable rather than a `char[]`

Whenever an explicit action command is not set, the text in the component will be sent to the `ActionEvent` constructor though you didn't specifically set it as action command. The `command` parameter can be `null` though, but it is not recommended to be `null`, therefore the text in the component is the action command by default. If there is no password in the `JPasswordField` an empty string will be the action command.

Don't try setting action command to `null`, if it is `null`, then the text in the `JPasswordField` will be the action command. The problem comes again.

So i would recommend you to set some action command for the `JPasswordField` without leaving it like that for now until this is rectified by Oracle.

```
JPasswordField jt=new JPasswordField("text");
        jt.setActionCommand("");
        jt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                System.out.println(ae.getActionCommand());
            }
        });
```