# Getting password from JTextField using PrepareStatement object

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I am creating a simple login application in java netbeans. I have made a connection with a MS-Access database in which i am storing the usernames and their passwords.

Suppose if I want to get text from a JTextField, i would use an object of PrepareStatement for the query. For Example 'ps' is the object of PrepareStatement, now to get text from JTextField i write, `ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());`

As `JPasswordField` returns a **character array**, how can i get password from the `JPasswordField` using `PrepareStatement` object 'ps' ?

Comment: And hint: there is a reason that Swing has a special JPasswordField, and that this thing is returning a char[] and not a string. If you are serious about what you are doing, you really have to study and **understand** such details; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983964/why-does-jpasswordfield-getpassword-create-a-string-with-the-password-in-it for example.

Comment: yeah i know why it returns a character array, that's why i asked if there was another way of getting password from JPasswordField without having to convert it in String like the one suggested below.

Comment: It's designed this way specifically for security reasons. The alternative is creating your own prepared statement implementation that overloads setString to take a char[] array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new `String` from the `char[]`.

```
ps.setString(1, new String(jPasswordField.getPassword()));
```