# java.sql.SLQException: Illegal operation on empty result set

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I got a login system in java and i want to get de user, password and type of user from database. But when i run the programe i got the folowing error: java.sql.SLQException: Illegal operation on empty result set
Code:

```
    conn=MysqlConnect.ConnectDB();
    String Sql="Select*from utilizador where Nome='" + Username +"' and Password='" + Password +"' and Permissao'" + Permissao + "'" ;

    try{
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Sql);
        int permissao = rs.getInt("Permissao");
        String nome = rs.getString("Nome");
        String password = rs.getString("Password");

        if(rs.next()){
```

Comment: 1. use prepared statements. 2. Your query is lacking a ``=`` at the ``permissao`` part. 3. read the exception message. It's trying to tell you something.

Comment: `Permissao'XYZ'`?? Did you even read your own query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has various issues:

- You missed an `=` after `and Permissao`
- From your code it seems you are looking for a user filtering by the following fields: Username, Password and Permissao, so you should have 3 variables defined
- You are trying to access the ResultSet (using `rs.getXXX`) before selecting any rows. After the `executeQuery` method you "fill" a ResultSet but his index is not pointing to any valid "database rows" so you need to call "rs.next()" in order to move the index to the first row. Consecutive calls move the index ahead of 1 position every time until the ResultSet finishes.

Having said so, you should:

1. Use a prepared statement that prevents sql injection and other typo/character errors as it automatically escapes parameter values.
2. In the prepared statement use `?` to define the parameters you'll need to set using `s.set<TypeOfField>`
3. Check if `ResultSet` has rows before using `rs.get`
4. Close connection, statement, and result set in the finally clause, so the resources will be closed either if there is or there is not an exception. Doing so you will prevent memory leak due to opened resources that you are not using anymore.
5. You should have 3 variable to perform the select: (I suppose)

   - Username of type String
   - Password of type String
   - Permissao of type int/Integer

Try using the following code, adapted to your needs.

```
    Connection c = DB.dbConnect(null);
    PreparedStatement s = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        final String SQL = " Select * from utilizador where Nome=? and Password=? and Permissao = ? ";

        s = c.prepareStatement(SQL);

        int i = 1;
        s.setString(i++, Username);
        s.setString(i++, Password);
        s.setInt(i++, Permissao);

        rs = s.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
             int permissao = rs.getInt("Permissao");
             String nome = rs.getString("Nome");
             String password = rs.getString("Password");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {          
        // exception handler
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            if (s != null)
                s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }try {
            if (c != null)
                c.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd look to suggest that you answer the question first (that is why this error occurs (ie: no call to `rs.next()` before using `getXXX`), and then proceed to address the other problems in the code in the question. That makes it more obvious that you are actually answering the question.

Comment: it gives me the folow error at " s.setString(i++, Username);/ s.setString(i++, Password);

Comment: it gives me the folow error at " s.setString(i++, Username);/ s.setString(i++, Password);
incompatible types: JPasswordField cannot be converted to String

Comment: You should have `Username, Passord and Permissao` respectivly as `String,String, Integer`. So you need to cast/extract the value before set the statement using `s.setXXX`

Comment: For your problem about JPasswordField check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983964/why-does-jpasswordfield-getpassword-create-a-string-with-the-password-in-it

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks, I updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks!!!! Problem solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the issue is with your query which is lacking proper quotes and spaces. It should be

```
   String Sql="Select * from utilizador where Nome = '" + Username +"' and Password='" + Password +"' and Permissao = '" + Permissao + "'" ;
```

Comment: I don't think fixing quotes is the right thing to do here - they should be using prepared statements properly and not dumping unsanitized values directly into the SQL in the first place.

Comment: Something like ``SELECT*FROM`` looks wrong, but it works in MySql. The real problem is the missing ``=`` at the last condition.

Comment: @JonK, absolutely but to start with is what I suggested.

Comment: @f1sh, yes nice catch. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: i put the "=", it keeps giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Bad looking, unreadable code.

Here's your problem:

```
    String nome = rs.getString("Nome");
    String password = rs.getString("Password");
```

You try to access values from the ResultSet before checking to see if it has any rows.

Comment: I'm a recent learner, it's the first programe i do by my self

Comment: I would say it's unusual for a first program to involve relational databases.  Do yourself a favor: learn the Java coding standards, follow them religiously, and start paying attention to formatting and style.  Your code is hard to read.  It'll make it harder for you and others to read and understand your code.