# How can i change JPasswordField into String

Tags: java, string, jpasswordfield

I want to connect my IDE to Oracle SQL Developer.
Therefore  I have to use this line of code:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
```

To enter the password I am using this:

```
JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
```

I would like to know how I can convert this JPasswordField into a String, so I can use the "Connect" line of Code I(This line only works with Strings)

EDIT: This is the code for entering the password. I found it here on stackoverflow:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter password:");
      JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
      panel.add(label);
      panel.add(pass);
      String[] options = new String[]{"OK", "Cancel"};
      int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "      Password for Database Connection",
                               JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                               null, options, options[0]);
```

Comment: `new String(pass.getPassword())`.

Comment: This does not work. In this line "getConnection" is underlined red because "pass" is not a String...?

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, pass);

Comment: No, because `pass` is a `JPasswordField`. As I said, `new String(pass.getPassword())` yields the contents of the password field as a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String passText = new String(pass.getPassword());
```

See [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983964/why-does-jpasswordfield-getpassword-create-a-string-with-the-password-in-it) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You just simply cast the the pass.getPassword() into string like this:

```
String stringPass = new String(pass.getPassWord());
```

but that defeats the security purpose of `JPasswordField`. Make sure to overwrite the `pass.getPassWord()` which is of type char[] since String stays in the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) until it's garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have some kind of submit button somewhere which will call the method doing the connection.

You will be able to retrieve the content of the `JPasswordField`by calling the `getPassword` method which provide a `char[]`.

Converting from char[] can be done by calling `String.valueOf`